# Why does Pytorch need `torch.cuda.is_available()` to be called for it to run?

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia

This is bugging me as some weird behaviour and I'm hoping someone has met with a similar situation.

Basically my application starts in Nvidia Docker2, and shows the `no CUDA-capable device is detected` error until I add a line `torch.cuda.is_available()`, then it magically starts working again.

I've only managed to gather that its not some race condition on what I can control, and calling other cuda runtime commands don't have the same effect.

So now I need to add the line somewhere before I run my pytorch application and I'm baffled as to why?

edit 1:
torch.cuda.init() also works, so the question is then why does torch.cuda.is_available() work

Comment: Maybe run `torch.cuda.is_initialized()` and see if torch.cuda is initialized, it can happen sometimes that it's not initialized on demand..

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel i tried and it gives False, but trying again after that doesn't work until I call `torch.cuda.is_available()`

Comment: call `torch.cuda.init()`

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel it works! now the real problem is ... why does torch.cuda.is_available() work?

Comment: I think is_available() internally calls init() first :)